# Oracle SQL Developer - Cannot read packages

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-grant

I have 2 users : UserA and UserB

UserA owns packages and procedures.
I want UserB to be able to READ those packages and procedures, and not execute or modify them.

so I did this :

```
grant debug any  procedure to UserB;
```

Using Toad, UserB can now read UserA's packages.

But using Oracle SQL Developer, this is not working.

Is there an option in SQL Developer than I need to enable?
Or do I need to grant more things to userB ?

I am using Oracle 10g R2

Comment: Why? What's the purpose of this requirement?

Comment: UserA is the application Owner in Production, UserB is for developers in production as well, that is read only on the Application's tables. Developers want to be able to read sources to make sure the correct versions are installed.

Comment: We use packages that contain a function that returns the package version number. The version number is automatically updated by source control. This way you can query the package and find out what version is in the database.

Comment: Yes but unfortunately we cannot implement this kind of solution with existing packages in production. We are looking for some grant / sql developer solution.

Comment: Why not make a copy of the database and have development work on that?

Comment: READ as in view the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're used to using Toad, Sql developer interface is similar but a bit different.  I'm guessing here, but you're probably Connecting as UserB, and expecting to see all schema objects under Connections.  However, in Sql Developer, what is shown under Connections is only objects owned by that connected user, not all objects.

You want to use "Schema Browser" in Sql Developer.  To do this, just right click onto the UserB connection and choose Schema Browser.  You will then have a drop-down at the top left corner of the page to select the owner you wish (UserA in this case).  The second drop-down under that is to select the type of object (table, function, procedure, package, etc...)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am using SQL Developer 2.1.1.64 but I cannot find this "Schema Browser" option.

Comment: @guigui42 thats very old version.  You should really get the latest (3.2) [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)  Also, 4.0 is almost out.  If using Windows, you probably want the download option with the jre (easier, just download, extract the zip, and run the exe in the sqldeveloper folder)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just downloaded the latest, and UserB can see UserA's packages without doing anything special... It was probably a bug in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

Updating SQL Developer from version 2.1.1.64 to 3.2 solved the problem.